# Como mudar a paginação wodpress para carregar mais

Tags: wordpress, paginação, template

Temo um site em wordpress, thema é o TOTAL.
Na paginação desse tema, são os números de páginas e as setas anterior e próximo.
O que eu quero é substituir essa paginação por um botão carregar mais, onde o usuário clicará para carregar mais posts e portfolio.

Resumindo, substituir a paginação padrão para um botão carregar mais.

Descobri que o arquivo que carrega o portfolio é o vcex_portfolio_grid.php

A área da paginação é essa aqui:

```
// Display pagination if enabled
        if ( 'true' == $atts['pagination']
            || ( 'true' == $atts['custom_query'] && ! empty( $wpex_query->query['pagination'] ) )
        ) {
            $output .= wpex_pagination( $wpex_query, false );
        }

    $output .= '</div>';

    // Reset the post data to prevent conflicts with WP globals
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala parceiro!

Você vai substituir aquela paginação padrão do Wordpress pelo seguinte código:

```
<div class="fetch">
    <?php next_posts_link( __( 'Carregar mais posts', 'nome-do-tema' ) ); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.fetch a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('loading').text('Carregando...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).attr('href') + '#boxes',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(out) {
            result = $(out).find('#boxes .box');
            nextlink = $(out).find('.fetch a').attr('href');
            $('#boxes').append(result);
            $('.fetch a').removeClass('loading').text('Carregar mais posts');
            if (nextlink != undefined) {
                $('.fetch a').attr('href', nextlink);
            } else {
                $('.fetch').remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Se ainda não funcionar, verifique no console do navegador se a função que te passei não está sendo reconhecida. Daí basta testar, mudando a função de local, ou seja, deixando acima ou abaixo do jquery principal.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção irmão! Desculpa a ignorância, mas isso eu faço no arquivo **functions.php** do tema (TOTAL)?

Comment: Não amigo.. Você deve inserir no próprio arquivo do template, onde se encontra o include da sua paginação padrão. Ou seja, basta substituir por tudo isso que te mandei, deixando no mesmo local que estava a padrão.

Comment: No arquivo referente a paginação do portfolio, aparece assim a área:
 // Display pagination if enabled
  if ( 'true' == $atts['pagination']
   || ( 'true' == $atts['custom_query'] && ! empty( $wpex_query->query['pagination'] ) )
  ) {
   $output .= wpex_pagination( $wpex_query, false );
  }

 $output .= '</div>';

 // Reset the post data to prevent conflicts with WP globals
 wp_reset_postdata();

Comment: Hum! Então você está usando um template customizado, diferente do que já vem no pacote do Wordpress. No seu caso, será preciso analisar com mais atenção pra poder substituir a função que passei. Tem como me informar o nome do template que está usando?

Comment: Claro, é o TOTAL - https://themeforest.net/item/total-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/6339019 . Para o portfolio estou usando o modulo do tema

Comment: Amigo, você vai ter que ir testando, trocando por esse código que te passei. Se o seu tema fosse o padrão que vem no Wordpress, seria muito mais fácil. Enfim, sempre uso esse código nos meus sites e funciona de boa!